# Spawning Isolates in for loop and processing parallelly in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, parallel-processing, dart-pub, dart-isolates

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
   ..............preprocessing(pr)...........
   ..... = await someFunc(someData[i]) (this line spawns off new Isolate)
   ..............postprocessing(po)..........
   }
```

I am writing this kind of function in dart and what I expect is to get this order pr0 -->someFunc(data[0]) --> pr1 --> someFunc(data[1]) --> post processing of whichever (Isolate finishes first ). But I know that I cant get the same effect using for loop. It is giving me of the order pr0 --> someFunc(data[0]) --> pr1 --> someFunc(data[1]) --> po0 --> po1.
How should I implement to get the above effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `Future.wait` instead (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/Future/wait.html).

```dart
final results = await Future.wait([
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) someFunc(someData[i]),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks ! above solution works. I have been advised another method as well.
 for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
  someFunc(data[i]).then(){
   //postprocessing..
  }
 }

I undertand the difference. if we follow above method event loop will have pick it up as and
when someFunc() finishes and it will put the listener to stack to process..

In the method suggested by you, It will wait till all of the someFunc finishes then we can
do postProcessing of each one by one.

Even though I think listener approach is faster, your approach seems cleaner. which one do
you suggest ?

Thank You.

Comment: @VarunHegde The part I don't like about the alternative you bring up is that you don't have an easy way to tell when everything has completed (which may or may not be a problem depending on use case). That said, you could actually combine both approaches. If you add a `.then` to `someFunc(someData[i])` in my solution above, it should allow you to both do the post processing as soon as possible, and also track when everything has completed.